# Custom control disappears from object browser

Tags: vb.net

My question is on how custom controls should be updated.

I downloaded [this owner drawn custom control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26622/Custom-Button-Control-with-Gradient-Colors-and-Ext), which I built, then copied the DLL to the Debug folder of the project and loaded it into the toolbox from there.

I decided to use this button on another project. I was mildly surprised to see the control was still in the toolbox but it seemed to work just fine. I decided to change this custom button's behavior. The button in the toolbox referenced the old version number. So I deleted it and loaded the newly rebuilt DLL.

**Now come the problems.** The first application--the one where the DLL was added to the toolbox from--still runs okay, but the second application is throwing errors, saying, `Type 'CButtonLib.CButton' is not defined`. When I add the button to a form, it appears okay. I can change its properties and it shows up in the code windows and in the object browser. **But as soon as I try to run it and it throws the errors, it no longer appears in the object browser**. References in the code window lose their intellisense.

Things I've tried include:

- Copying the DLL to the project's debug and release folders and loading them into the toolbox from there.
- Removing it from the toolbox altogether and just adding a reference then copying and pasting  a button directly from the first project.
- Copying in a form with a CButton on it from the first project.
- Scouring the internet for answers
- Swearing at the computer.

Nothing seems to work and I've now spent over a day trying to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did get to the bottom of this. In the end I simply had to recreate the entire custom control project using a different name. I suspect the way I added the original project to the toolbox of a *different* program – as opposed to adding it within the test project it came with – may have had something to do with it, but that's just a guess. Anyway, I can amend and update the new control without problem now, so all's well that ends well. :-)